# Select results of past events

Tags: mysql

I have a table with events data. Some of the events that took place in the past. Some of them could be today, just earlier.

There are two columns that can help determine these future events:

eventData (datetime)
eventTime (varchar/5)

The problem is that eventTime is in military format, like 14:30. How do I get around this?

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE(eventData ) <= CURDATE()
AND eventTime < CURTIME()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP to solve this. replace CURTIME() with a PHP function:

```
$cur_time = date('G:i');
```

And compare columns using variable:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE(eventData ) <= CURDATE()
AND eventTime < '$cur_time'
```

Or you can use time_format mysql function like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM events
WHERE DATE(eventData ) <= CURDATE()
AND eventTime < TIME_FORMAT(CURTIME(), '%h:%i')
```